# How can I get available commands controllers and actions?

Tags: php, yii

I am assuming that is it possible to get list of available controllers and actions of console applications from web application?

I just want to view how many cron functions are created on my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create console command to list or count all your commands. For example:

```
class CounterCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{
    public function run($args){
        $runner=$this->getCommandRunner();
        $commands=$runner->commands; // here you will get all your commands
        echo "Following commands available: \r\n";
        echo ' - '.implode("\n - ",array_keys($commands));
        echo "Count of commands is - ".count($commands)."\n";
    }
}
```

You can store it somewhere, and use in web app.

Otherwise watch at command runner parser and implement it in web app.